# How to adjust image inside imageView?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview

Is there a way I can smaller down the image size which placed inside the imageView?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/Date"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Date"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/deep_sky_blue"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:hint="Date"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/Amount"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Amount"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:textColor="@color/deep_sky_blue"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:hint="Amount"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="265dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/Comments"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Comments"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:textColor="@color/deep_sky_blue"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:hint="Comments"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:id="@+id/line2"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="356dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the design looked in android studio

[image]

But when I run in real device, it gives me another look.

[image]

What is the best approach to solve this ? Thanks

Comment: check if your app supports multiple screen sizes

Comment: A quick fix is you can use Linear layout and give weight to the views instead of relative layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase the size of android:width and android:height in camera.xml in drawable folder. this will solve your problem

Here is your xml for camera, name it as cam_icon.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M12,12m-3.2,0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,6.4 0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,-6.4 0"/>
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M9,2L7.17,4L4,4c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v12c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h16c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L22,6c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2h-3.17L15,2L9,2zM12,17c-2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5s2.24,-5 5,-5 5,2.24 5,5 -2.24,5 -5,5z"/>
```

Comment: I need to create a .xml drawable folder ?

Comment: no if you are using image, then increase the size of image, or you can use an xml camera icon, which will took less space and also perfect in every screen

Comment: If I increase imageview size, the image size will increase too

Comment: absolutely, use xml . this icon is already present in android assert folder.

Comment: Just rightclick on drawable-->new-->vertor asset-->now click on the below android icon, it will open all icon for you. You can choose your icon from it.

Comment: I only see image asset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130843/discussion-between-seng-and-ranjan-das).